# Weighted Avg for Billable Hour

Tags: statistics, average, percentages

I am trying to get to an avg reimbursement rate for an MD billable hour.  They have different types of appointments, each receiving a different reimbursement amount.  I ran an analysis which gave the historical mix of appointments across all the MDs.  Looks something like this:

```
Appt.  % of Time Appt Occurred.  Reimb Amt.
A      30%                       $50
B      50%                       $65
C      20%                       $90
```

Obviously from this I could get an weighted avg reimbursement amount of $65.50 per appointment.  The problem is that I need to get to an avg reimb amt per hour.  Each of these appointments have varying lengths.  The data set would be something like this:

```
Appt.  Appt Duration(Mins).  % of Time Appt Occurred.  Reimb Amt.
A      15                    30%                       $50
B      30                    50%                       $65
C      45                    20%                       $90
```

The added complexity of the time component has me stumped.  How can I get to an avg hourly reimbursement rate?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find hourly reimbursement rate for each kind of appointment, then get the weighted average for the three kinds:

For the first kind: $\$50/(1/4) = \$200,$ etc.

Then $\$200(.3) + ?(.5) + ?(.2) = $ answer.

Comment: Oh gosh, yeah that makes sense.  Thank you